# Collection of older EPROM IC's

Tags: hardware, rom, intel, motorola-68000

I acquired a collection of older EPROM IC's and am wondering what the rarity of them are or if they are rather common. Do people collect these items?

- 89142   NM27C512Q
- ~~  B9212   NM27C512Q
- ~~  B9312   NM27C512Q
- ~~  B9224   NM27C512Q
- ~~  B9318   NM27C512Q
- ~~  B9130   NM27C512Q
- A   8740    2716Q
- Allen Bradley   AM27C2048
- AMD 2764ADC
- AMD AM27C64
- AMD     AM27C64-20QDSB  AM27C64-20ADSB
- AMD     9232EP  AM27C512-255DC
- Fujitsu / Intel 8628 19 MBL8742H
- Fujitsu / Intel MBL 8742H
- Intel '80   8627P   L8300363
- Intel '80   8641P   L6460221
- Intel '80   8644P   L6460220
- Intel '80   8726P   L7290058
- Intel '80   8627P   L6300365
- Intel '82   D8742   L4255697
- Intel '82   D8742   L5360036 / L6110132
- Intel '82   8441    8441FDD
- Intel '82   D8742   L4195392
- Intel '82   DM742   L8130114 – 308262
- Intersil    8201    IM64021PL
- Intersil    7929    IM64021PL
- Mitsubishi Elect Corp   D8742
- Motorola    8013    MCM2716C-35
- Motorola    185-08
- Motorola    185-09
- Motorola    8448D XM    SC81192L
- Motorola    8504C XM    SC81192L
- NEC D8741AD
- NEC D8302P9
- NEC D8348PX
- NEC D8321P9
- NEC D8320P9
- NEC D8352PX
- NEC 595304A NM27C512Q
- SEEQ    8450A   27128-25
- SEEQ    0517 A  2764-20
- STMicroelectronics  3210F
- STMicroelectronics  10F 1 L / 9604
- STMicroelectronics  9318    M27C4002
- STMicroelectronics  9335S   M27C4002
- STMicroelectronics  10F I L 96004v5 MYS 88 530
- STMicroelectronics  96004 V5    M27C 1001
- STMicroelectronics  9335S   M27C4002
- STMicroelectronics      M27C4002
- STMicroelectronics  9340B   M274002
- STMicroelectronics  9340B   M27C4002
- STMicroelectronics  9G004   MYS 88 530
- STMicroelectronics  9235    MC27C4002
- STMicroelectronics  9301    MC27C4002
- STMicroelectronics  9340B   MC27C4002
- STMicroelectronics  9335S   M2732A-2FL
- TMS JL  27c240-15   LP9245184
- TMS JL  27c240-15   LP9245157
- TMS JL  27c240-15   LP92451B4

Comment: Welcome to Retrocomputing Stack Exchange. Some parts of your question, such as the "common marketplace", are off-topic for this site, but other than that your question seems OK.

Comment: Check cpu-world forum if you want to see some serious collectors...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chip collectors I know are generally looking for a few things:

- **Early production dates** — chips often have a date code of the form `YYWW` (eg `8651` for the 51st week of 1986). The earliest ones have more value to collectors.
- **Unusual technologies** — if a chip used a short-lived or esoteric technology, it's generally considered more ‘interesting’.
- **Non-standard packaging** — anything but DIP: mil-spec ceramics, piggybacks, Eastern Bloc rarities or regular chips in metal cans, …
- **Specific applications** — At the hobbyist level, Commodore/MOS produced a lot of chips with non-standard pinouts, and these originals are now getting rarer. Industrially, there are many infrastructure/transit projects that run on 30+ year old systems. These may require one particular EPROM type for system modifications.
- **Provenance** — if a chip or board comes with verifiable information where it was used (say aerospace, or motor racing) then it would have additional collector value. This might also apply if an EPROM contained a known early ROM version for a commercial computer.

EPROMs were usually produced in quantity, were designed to be interchangeable and used very standard technology. I'd say they were more useful than valuable, though UV-erasable EPROMs do have a certain visual appeal.